# Why is the standard definition of a $(p, q)$-tensor so bizarre?

Tags: soft-question, mp.mathematical-physics, mathematics-education, definitions, multilinear-algebra

At time of writing the first definition of a $ (p, q) $-tensor on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) is as follows.

---

**Definition.** A $ (p, q) $-tensor is an assignment of a multidimensional array $$ T^{i_1\dots i_p}_{j_{1}\dots j_{q}}[\mathbf{f}] $$
to each basis $\mathbf{f}$ of an $n$-dimensional vector space such that, if we apply the change of basis
$\mathbf{f}\mapsto \mathbf{f}\cdot R $
then the multidimensional array obeys the transformation law
$$
  T^{i'_1\dots i'_p}_{j'_1\dots j'_q}[\mathbf{f} \cdot R] = \left(R^{-1}\right)^{i'_1}_{i_1} \cdots \left(R^{-1}\right)^{i'_p}_{i_p} T^{i_1, \ldots, i_p}_{j_1, \ldots, j_q}[\mathbf{f}] R^{j_1}_{j'_1}\cdots R^{j_q}_{j'_q} .
$$

---

This is a standard definition I can remember reading in textbooks during my undergraduate degree. To me, it also seems far too confusing. To understand a $ (p, q) $-tensor as an element in 
$$ \text{Hom}(\underbrace{V^* \otimes\dots\otimes V^*}_{p\text{}} \otimes \underbrace{V \otimes\dots\otimes V}_{q \text{}}, \mathbb{K}) $$
one only has to understand the tensor product on vector spaces (which is easy to define in terms of bases). To then recover the description of a multidimensional array one also has understand cobases, however these can also be easily explained constructively.

### Question

**Why would anyone give the standard definition?**

I initially thought the answer lay in applied mathematics. However linear maps are omnipresent in applied mathematics and I have never seen a linear map defined as a function on bases that satisfies coherence with respect to base change. Furthermore I feel the consensus would be that this is a bad definition from a pedagogical point of view (I certainly think it is). So why is the analogous definition of $ (p, q) $-tensors standard?

Comment: Physicists and Computer Scientists are why

Comment: When you do long computations in coordinates, operations like contractions and similar become automatic by using upper and lower indices. Or, at least, I have been told so :)

Comment: More seriously, the notion of "dual vector space" is often a delicate one, at least for non-mathematicians. Computations in coordinates can be less transparent than coordinate-free ones, but they can be grasped more easily by people whose background in abstract linear algebra is not strong.

Comment: Einstein was using that definition in the early 1900. Whitney came up with the modern definition in 1940 or so. Obviously the "standard definition" (coordinatewise) is easier to understand, but less nice to think about than abstract tensor products.

Comment: "Einstein was using that definition in the early 1900". Let us recall that, without the deep work of T. Levi-Civita, no mathematical formulation of General Relativity could have been possible.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi and Ricci you do not mention?

Comment: @EinfacherSchreiberling: right, of course.

Comment: But what confuses me is that the alternative definition doesn't have to be 'coordinate-free' (if that's what puts people off). The tensor product can be defined with respect to bases!

Comment: Physicists use Riemannian geometry as it stood around 1900-1920, pre-Cartan, Ehresmann etc etc. They haven't updated the definition to keep pace with mathematical perceptions.

Comment: @ David Roberts, you are right. However, they have some arguments in doing so. (this is what i am trying to explain in my answer).

Comment: I still like the definition I learned from my undergraduate differential geometry / linear algebra professor.  "A vector is like a cabbage.  A linear functional is like a goat, it eats a cabbage and spits out a number.  [A goat with an unusual digestive system, I guess].  A $(p,q)$ tensor is like a dragon that eats $p$ goats and $q$ cabbages, and spits out a number."

Comment: "this is a bad definition from a pedagogical point of view". Why do you think so?

Comment: @EinfacherSchreiberling "Obviously the "standard definition" is easier to understand..." The fact that the OP posed this question and is getting up-votes seems to contradict this assumption.

Comment: @DavidRoberts do you mean Elie or Henri Cartan?

Comment: @Michael Élie (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89lie_Cartan#Differential_Geometry). All the amazing new geometry he did that people at the time had a hard time with.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold I learned about tensors for the purposes of GR from an old physics book in my first year of university. It was a long time before I realised that tensors are tuples of _functions of the coordinates_, not just symbols, which is why the coordinate transformation rules are so important. It just wasn't said that they were not just arrays of numbers!

Comment: @DavidRoberts do you know if Élie used the modern definition of tensor? I had the impression he didn't, at least not for 1-forms in his works around 1900. I still don't know when the modern definition arose and hope someone answers this [question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/464).

Comment: @MichaelBächtold  apparently he knew enough to grasp the concept of fibre bundle, which is more than the old approach, though it might have been implicit. That's why i included Ehresmann :-)

Comment: I think the first definition is already beyond what physicists and computer scientists are comfortable with (and should not be branded as standard). But being an article on wikipedia, it makes sense to have a definition that satisfies mathematician's demand of precision, while also making it clear to the reader how in the world it has to do with a multi-dimensional array. Even in a purely math context, one may also want to put out a definition that is easy to work with (such as a line bundle as a collection of "functions" over open sets that satisfy similar transformation rules).

Comment: @NateEldredge:   That cabbage/goat mnemonic only works if you remember that a cabbage can also eat a goat.

Comment: Here’s a similar situation: an orientation of a manifold is often defined as an assignment of ordered basis at each point, smoothly varying, modulo GL(n) with positive determinant. Very cumbersome. The short definition would be a volume form, i.e., a non-vanishing n-form. I’d say the long definition should be kept informal, or not branded as definition at all.

Comment: You can see online how Einstein would have learned tensors, following Ricci and Levi-Civita's paper in the Annalen from 1900: https://eudml.org/doc/157997.  It has applications to analysis (quadratic forms), geometry (embedded surfaces), mechanics (integrable vector fields), and physics (electrodynamics, thermodynamics, elasticity).

Comment: @liuyao: the first definition of orientation you provide seems wrong to me: it seems you are *first* taking a global frame, and *then* modding out by global $GL^+_n$-valued functions. But a manifold, to admit a global frame at all, needs to be parallelizable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold). The correct definition of orientation $\mathfrak{o}$, as you suggest, is a global volume form $\eta$ modulo the multiplication of strictly positive global functions: $\mathfrak{o}=[\eta]=\eta\cdot C^\infty (M,\mathbb{R}_{>0})$.

Comment: coordinate-free v.s coordinate-full

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think that the answer lies in the "educational culture" of physicists. Physicists are often used -well at least at the undergraduate level- to learn and perform  complicated computations with abstract objects, without caring much about the structure and the abstract properties of the ambient spaces containing these abstract objects.
The definition of tensors as "generalized" vectors or matrices, with covariant and contravariant components, is one of such examples: Starting from such a definition, enables one to quickly learn how to perform computations with tensors, without demanding a deep understanding of the abstract definition of tensor products let alone dual spaces, manifolds, tangent and cotangent spaces or bundles etc. In this way, an undergraduate physicist quickly becomes able to perform computations in a wide range of topics (from classical mechanics to special and general relativity and from continuoum mechanics to electromagnetism and even field theories) while in most cases (s)he misses a deeper understanding of where all these objects "live".

Furthermore, this "educational culture" seems to be supported by the fact that the definition of tensors via their transformation properties usually arises -in physics texts- through phenomenological or semi-phenomenological considerations: For example studying vectors vs gradients or more generally from the study and  generalization of the transformatiom properties of basis vectors vs the transformation properties of the coordinates of a vector expressed with respect to this basis. This is actually the way physicists are usually introduced to

> understand cobases in a constructive way

(to borrow the terminology of the OP). A very clear and instructive exposition along these lines, emphasizing the phenomenological origin of this approach, can be found in chapters 2 and 3, of the classic text of B. Schutz, [A first course in general relativity](https://www.fis.unam.mx/~max/mecanica/b_Schutz.pdf).

**Edit:** Maybe it would be important at this point, to note that the description of the transformation rules of displacement, velocity and acceleration vectors, under coordinate changes, are among the most fundamental and delicate problems of mechanics, if one is to build coherent definitions of these notions, to survive experiments ranging from subatomic to astronomical. They are pervading physical theories from the Galilean perception and Newtonian mechanics to relativity theory and continuoum mechanics  and from Maxwell's electromagnetism to modern quantum field theories.
There are profound reasons for this: In physics, a system of coordinates (or a system of reference) is actually an observer. The study of the transformation rules of physical quantities, under coordinate or base changes, is not simply a theoretical exercise. It is actually a necessary step in the development of any physical theory, in the sense that it enables the seamless communication between different observers, that is between different experiments, which is crucial in accepting or rejecting any physical theory.
(On the other hand it should not be ignored that in the research level, modern theoretical physics strives for global and coordinate free descriptions. In my understanding this reflects the desire to pass from phenomenological descriptions to more fundamental theories).

**P.S.:** I am not sure i really agree with the use of the term "standard definition" in the OP. My first degree was on physics. I then joined the grad school on pure mathematics. I  had a good "working understanding" of contravariant and covariant components, contractions, metric tensors, upper and lower indices etc. and i was quite comfortable in performing calculations with such objects. I still remember my astonishment when i first understood the abstract definition of the tensor product and its universal property, and notions such as dual spaces etc. I was striving -for weeks-  to make the connections between the two definitions. When i finally managed to put things in some order in my head and to link what i already knew with what i learned in the grad school, i really felt something very important had happened to me: I felt i finally got to understand the ... "standard definition" ;)

(At the beginning of the grad school, i was desperately asking for help from my fellow students (most of them were coming from the undergrad math school) with the algebraic definition of the tensor product and the related notions (quotient spaces, universal properties etc). I still remember, and they probably also do, their surprise when they realized how easy were actual computations for me and when they started asking for my help with raising and lowering indices ... )

To conclude with a note on terminology: having read carefully through the various comments to the OP and to this post, i think that it might be sensible to speak of the present definition as the "**phenomenological definition of a tensor**", rather than the "standard definition", or the "physicist's definition" or the "pre-1930's mathematician's definition" or the "indices definition", just to collect a few of the terms that have been of use.

Comment: Konstantinos, however this lack of connection between the two definitions in textbooks creates a problem. Pedagogically it would be correct to discuss the different definitions and relations between them from the very begining.

Comment: Hi Sergei! Nice to see you here! Of course i agree with your comment. However, this  would require a "multidisciplinary" approach from the professors teaching different courses even in the grad school: for example the "indices" definition is usually pursued in introductory courses on differentiable manifolds and riemannian geometry while the algebraic definition is usually pursued in general abstract algebra courses.

Comment: I think it's a little unfair to call it the physicists' educational culture. Physicists care mostly about how things work and not  the abstract concepts we use to explain why things work the way they do. So they focus mostly on the quantities that need to be calculated and the rules the calculations have to follow. They need to know how to use physical information to set up the inputs to a calculation and at the end interpret the outputs of the calculation as physical consequences. They have their own plausibiity arguments for deriving the right rules of calculations from physical principles.

Comment: @Deane Yang, yes i would sign every word you say. I completely agree. By no means did i want to use the term "physicists educational culture" in a derogatory way.(see also my comment after David Roberts' comment at the OP).

Comment: @DeaneYang , I, on the contrary, would add critical notes to the observation of Konstantinos. I do not like this solipsism, in which physicists live (and not only they, this is a common phenomenon everywhere, including mathematics). Instead of seeking connections between disciplines that would make easier for people to understand the essence of things, scientists, on the contrary, seem to try to divide science, as if pursuing the goal of making it as incomprehensible as possible. I would say, that is unfair.

Comment: maybe it would be useful to distinguish between undergaduate and graduate education at that point. Since there are different objectives and requirements in each.

Comment: Historically this "physicists definition" was probably also mathematicians definition up to ~1930. So I prefer to think of it as "pre 1930 vs post 1930 mathematicians" instead of "physicists vs. mathematicians".

Comment: @MichaelBächtold you are correct that mathematicians also used the ugly coordinate-dependent definition of tensors until the 1930s. And it's not true that all of physics is plagued with the "physicist's definition" of tensors: current textbooks on *general relativity* define tensors close to how the mathematicians  do.  See my discussion of tensor products in physics in the last section of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf.

Comment: Perhaps a useful example to consider: Electric and magnetic fields transform in a subtle way under a Lorentz transformation. One doesn't really know a priori how they'll transform; one must rely on experimental observation (phenomenology). In some sense, the "computational" or "physicist" version of the transformation law is the true starting point, since it's what nature presents us with phenomenologically. Of course we then develop our basis-independent theoretical account to explain things. But if you're experimentally-minded then the computational version is closer to actual observations.

Comment: By the end of the 19th century, lots of experiments suggested a very strange thing: the rules of transformation of velocity vectors between different  reference frames should leave one particular value of magnitude unaltered, that is the speed of light in vacuum $c$. Einstein posed this suggestion as an axiom and started the search for the correct transformation rules which turned out to be the Lorentz transformations. Special relativity rised as the triumph of phenomenology (in my opinion).

Comment: At the same time its mathematical formulation suggested that vectors are not enough: geometry had to be generalized to keep up with the phenomenological description suggested by a series of experiments. So, covectors or covariant and contravariant vectors, 1-forms, dualities, contractions, metric tensors, came into the picture, while phenomenology was generating pure theory, a route which has led to GR. This is the frame where the "physicists" or "standard" or "pre-1930's mathematician's" definition of a tensor in arbitrary dimensions was born.

Answer (score 2):

To define tensors as they are used in physics with the clarity and rigour that is used in mathematics, we would have to develop the notions of:

- the tensor product
- duals of vector spaces
- manifolds
- vector bundles
- the tangent bundle
- and finally, tensor bundles

This is quite a bit of work and it's not surprising then that physicists eschew all this and choose to stick to their traditional definition and which most likely helped motivate the discovery of the above notions.

Still, given the clarity it brings to the subject I think that this is a pity. Even more so when one realises how omnipresent the bundle picture is in gauge theories like Yang-Mills. However, to bring all this to the attention of physicists would mean reforming the physics curricula and this itself is no small bit of work.

Personally, I can't have been the first person to have noticed that a contravariant and covariant vector is simply not a vector, either in its axiomatic or geometric definition. Even without chasing the full curriculum reform that the subject deserves, it might be worth pointing out where these new concepts fit in with the traditional definition.

I also think it's worth pointing out that the categorical definition of a tensor makes it quite clear we don't need to think of tensors as multilinear functions - we can define them directly.
This merely underlines that there are a number of mathematical technologies that have been teased out of the traditional physical picture.

**edit**

I'm not able to enter comments with the phone that I have at the moment. So I'm answering comments here.

@Bachtold: The geometric picture of vectors that is usually found in most classical mechanics texts, and in the description of a vector that Einstein described in his semi-popular book, *The Evolution of Physics*. And the axiomatic definition that is found in most introductory books in linear algebra. And if my high-school curricula in a comprehensive school is any guide, in most schools.

Comment: Which definition of vector do you have in mind, when you conclude that contravariant and covariant vectors are not vectors?

Comment: Tensors can be added and multiplied with numbers, and these operations satisfy the usual axioms of a vector space, hence tensors are vectors.

Answer (score 1):

There are not just two, but at least 3 different ways to approach tensor products of vector bundles, each tailored to a different audience.

Intermediate between the "physicists' definition" mentioned in the question and the "definition in terms of tensor products of vector bundles" lies the "mathematician's pedagogical definition" which I remember encountering in do Carmo's textbook on Riemannian geometry (and I have the impression that it's widely used in introductory textbooks). Basically, this is just the definition in terms of tensor products in disguise, owing to the fact that **textbook writers in Riemannian geometry don't want to assume that a student is familiar with tensor products**. It seems that the author thinks in terms of tensor products, but avoids using the words "tensor product". In practice, this means they phrase everything in terms of the universal property of the tensor product, *defining* tensor products of (certain) vector bundles to be certain spaces of multilinear maps.

The category theorist in me is pleased that such a "hack" is made possible by thinking in terms of universal properties. The pedagogist in me is convinced that any math student who is exposed to vector spaces (an agreed-upon prerequisite for Riemannian geometry) *should* be exposed to tensor products. In an ideal world where this is the case, one could easily motivate the general definition of tensor product of vector bundles in an introductory Riemannian geometry course. Reasoning in terms of universal properties would still be useful, and would hopefully seem less mysterious to students.

Comment: In geometric analysis, it is helpful to think somewhere between the fully-coordinate based approach of physics and the universal property approach of algebraists. While the latter is conceptually simpler in terms of defining what a tensor is in the first place, if you want to really prove analytic inequalities about say, positive Ricci curvature, its likely that you are going to have to deal with the former.

Comment: As such, I suspect that many Riemannian geometers are really using this perspective when they introduce tensors to students. The goal is to compute curvature tensors and use their properties without getting too much into intricacies or working in full generality.